# tags$style applied to all Leaflet Maps in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, shinydashboard, r-leaflet

I'm able to change the cursor in an R [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) app regarding [r-leaflet](/questions/tagged/r-leaflet) but can't seem to figure out how to only do it for specific maps. It seems like the last `tags$style` is applied to all the previous maps? I've added a reprex with only two maps but the same logic can be applied to many more. Any help would be much appreciated as it's bugging the crap out of me! Thanks.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)

header = dashboardHeader(title = "Hydroclimatic Data")


# * sidebar ----
sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem(
      "Map",
      tabName = "map",
      menuSubItem("Map", tabName = "map", icon = icon("chart-line"))
    ),
    menuItem(
      "Map2",
      tabName = "map2",
      menuSubItem("Map2", tabName = "map2", icon = icon("chart-line"))
    )))



body = dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(
      tabName = "map",
      tags$style(type = 'text/css', '
      .leaflet-container {
  cursor: crosshair !important;}'),
      fluidRow(
        tabBox(width = 12, id = "tab",
               tabPanel("Map", style = "height:92vh;",leafletOutput("swe_maps"))))
      ),
    
    
    # * * -- Snotel - Raw ----
    tabItem(
      tabName = "map2",
      tags$style(type = 'text/css', '
      .leaflet-container {
  cursor: help !important;}'),
      fluidRow(
        tabBox(width = 12, id = "tabchart",
               tabPanel("Map", style = "height:92vh;",leafletOutput("swe_maps2")))))))
  
  # UI ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  ui <- dashboardPage(header = header, sidebar = sidebar, body = body)
  
  # Server ------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$swe_maps <- renderLeaflet({leaflet("map1") %>% addTiles()})
    
    
    output$swe_maps2 <- renderLeaflet({leaflet("map2") %>% addTiles()})
    
    
  }



##### RUN APPLICATION #####
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the class selector `.leaflet-container` within the css, use the Id selectors `#swe_maps` and `#swe_maps2`.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

header = dashboardHeader(title = "Hydroclimatic Data")


# * sidebar ----
sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem(
      "Map",
      tabName = "map",
      menuSubItem("Map", tabName = "map", icon = icon("chart-line"))
    ),
    menuItem(
      "Map2",
      tabName = "map2",
      menuSubItem("Map2", tabName = "map2", icon = icon("chart-line"))
    )))



body = dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(
      tabName = "map",
      tags$style(type = 'text/css', '
      #swe_maps {
  cursor: crosshair !important;}'),
      fluidRow(
        tabBox(width = 12, id = "tab",
               tabPanel("Map", style = "height:92vh;",leafletOutput("swe_maps"))))
    ),
    
    
    # * * -- Snotel - Raw ----
    tabItem(
      tabName = "map2",
      tags$style(type = 'text/css', '
      #swe_maps2 {
  cursor: help !important;}'),
      fluidRow(
        tabBox(width = 12, id = "tabchart",
               tabPanel("Map", style = "height:92vh;",leafletOutput("swe_maps2")))))))

# UI ----------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- dashboardPage(header = header, sidebar = sidebar, body = body)

# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$swe_maps <- renderLeaflet({leaflet("map1") %>% addTiles()})
  
  
  output$swe_maps2 <- renderLeaflet({leaflet("map2") %>% addTiles()})
  
  
}



##### RUN APPLICATION #####
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried the suggested code above but couldn't get it to work on the example code. The logic makes sense but for some reason the elementId in leaflet() and the styles are not 'clicking'.  Any suggestions? Can you get it to work on the code I provided?

Comment: @JoshErickson I have amended my answer to correct the error. It seems the map ID was already assigned in the `leafletOutput()` function call. You should use these in the css instead.